# How to pass time / manage a very long drive (25+ hours) with a group of people

Tags: usa, driving, road-trips

We have a group of 8 that are taking two vehicles on a long drive.  Our plan is to not have to stop besides for gas, food, and restrooms.

What is the best way to manage this scenario in terms of passing time, driver duty, etc.?

Our big rule so far is that the person riding shotgun must always be awake with the driver.

Comment: There is really no rule of thumb on this you pass the time and keep the driver awake in any way you can.  And not necessarily by the person riding shotgun.

Comment: Do all have driving licenses?

Comment: I thought about walkie talkies but of course you'll have phones. What if there's no cell signal?  Think about how to coordinate stops.

Comment: Cryostorage....

Comment: @Karlson Right, we just figured the people that would actually want to be sleeping could sit in the back so the minimum of two that are awake can sit together up front.

Comment: @gerrit Yep, we all have licenses.

Comment: @mkennedy Didn't think about that.  The plan would be to make the same stops the whole way through to avoid one group getting too far away from the other.  Maximum distance apart we would be planning on is a couple of miles.

Comment: You can get cheap CB Radios that (if coupled with a quality mag mount antenna) will generally have better range than FRS walkie talkies, plus you'll be able to communicate with trucks to find out about traffic conditions and police activity ahead. You still won't get more than a few miles of range, but it'll be better than a handheld walkie talkie inside the car. Just keep general chatter off of channel 19 or you'll annoy the truck drivers.